# How to execute oracle stored procedure from shell script?

Tags: stored-procedures, sh

We are in a process to automate maintaining deployment records in each environment for every component.
For that initial plan is to store this data into two Oracle DB tables:

1. DEPLOYMENTSTATUS
2. DEPLOYMENTSTATUS_ARCHIVE

    For that I have written two stored procedures. These stored procedures work fine when I execute them from sqldeveloper and records gets inserted/updated as expected.
   However, below shell scripts neither throwing any error not inserting/updating any records in tables mentioned above.
   Can anyone please help to identify and resolve the issue.

Stored Proc IN Parameters - P_PROJECT, P_MODULE, P_COMPONENT, P_BRANCH, P_VERSION, P_ENVIRONMENT, P_REASON

 Stored Proc OUT Parameters - SPRESULT OUT  VARCHAR2, SPRESPONSECODE OUT VARCHAR2, SPRESPONSEMESSAGE OUT VARCHAR2

Shell Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#This shell script invokes oracle stored procedures to insert/update deployment records.

#update below properties
PROJECT=$1
MODULE=$2
COMPONENT=$3
BRANCH=$4
VERSION=$5
TARGETENV=$6
REASON=$7
PROP_FILE=deployments_db.properties
LOGDIR=/home/${USER}/logs

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#                               DO NOT EDIT AFTER THIS LINE
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#create directory structure if it does not exist for storing log files
mkdir -p ${LOGDIR}/deployments-logs

#declare log file name
deployments_logfile=${LOGDIR}/deployments-logs/${PROJECT}_deployments_logfile_$(date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S").log

#create log file
touch $deployments_logfile

#function to read property file
function getProperty {
 PROP_KEY=$1
 PROP_VALUE=`cat $PROP_FILE | grep "$PROP_KEY" | cut -d'=' -f2`
 echo $PROP_VALUE
}
DB_HOSTNAME=$(getProperty "db.hostname")
DB_PORT=$(getProperty "db.port")
DB_SID=$(getProperty "db.sid")
DB_USERNAME=$(getProperty "db.username")
DB_PASSWORD=$(getProperty "db.password")

printf "\n\nFor more details please check logfiles created at - ${LOGDIR}/deployments-logs\n\n"
printf "\n**************************************************************************************************************************">>$deployments_logfile
printf "\n\t\t\t${PROJECT} - ${MODULE} - ${COMPONENT} - ${BRANCH} - ${VERSION} - ${TARGETENV}">>$deployments_logfile
printf "\n\t\t\t${REASON}">>$deployments_logfile
printf "\n\t\t\t${DB_USERNAME}/*******@${DB_HOSTNAME}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_SID}">>$deployments_logfile
printf "\n**************************************************************************************************************************\n\n">>$deployments_logfile

sqlplus -s ${DB_USERNAME}/${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_HOSTNAME}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_SID} << FIN_SQL >> $deployments_logfile
SET HEAD OFF;
SET TIME ON;
SET TIMING ON;
SET LINESIZE 1024;
SET PAGESIZE 9999;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
SPRESULT VARCHAR2(32);
SPRESPONSECODE VARCHAR2(64);
SPRESPONSEMESSAGE VARCHAR2(1024);
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Executing - CREATE_UPDATE_DEPLOYMENTSTATUS_RECORD');
CREATE_UPDATE_DEPLOYMENTSTATUS_RECORD('${PROJECT}','${MODULE}','${COMPONENT}','${BRANCH}','${VERSION}','${TARGETENV}','${REASON}', SPRESULT, SPRESPONSECODE, SPRESPONSEMESSAGE);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CONCAT('SPRESULT - ', SPRESULT));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CONCAT('SPRESPONSECODE - ', SPRESPONSECODE));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CONCAT('SPRESPONSEMESSAGE - ', SPRESPONSEMESSAGE));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Executing - CREATE_DEPLOYMENTSTATUS_ARCHIVE_RECORD');
CREATE_DEPLOYMENTSTATUS_ARCHIVE_RECORD('${PROJECT}','${MODULE}','${COMPONENT}','${BRANCH}','${VERSION}','${TARGETENV}','${REASON}', SPRESULT, SPRESPONSECODE, SPRESPONSEMESSAGE);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CONCAT('SPRESULT - ', SPRESULT));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CONCAT('SPRESPONSECODE - ', SPRESPONSECODE));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CONCAT('SPRESPONSEMESSAGE - ', SPRESPONSEMESSAGE));
END;
FIN_SQL

printf "\n\n**************************************************************************************************************************\n\n">>$deployments_logfile
exit
```

Properties File:

```
#cicd deployment record keeping db details
db.hostname=oracledbhost
db.port=1521
db.sid=orcl
db.username=cicduser
db.password=cicduser
```

LogFile Contents:

```
**************************************************************************************************************************
                        TestProject - NPM - TestProject_Notifications - develop - 1.0.0.123456789 - DEV
                        TEST
                        cicduser/*******@oracledbhost:1521/orcl
**************************************************************************************************************************



**************************************************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful if you can do some exception handling in your FIN_SQL to see whats going wrong.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to do that. I am able to execute FIN_SQL statements (as it is even without replacing shell variables) from sqldeveloper without any issue. I can see that record got created in both tables.